# Passing JSON in Django Template to Standalone Javascript File

Tags: javascript, json, django, django-templates, django-views

I have the following code in my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json, requests

platformReq = requests.get(platformUrl, headers={'Authorization': 'Token token="1234"'})

platformData = json.loads(platformReq.text)
return render_to_response('find.html',{'platformList':platformData})
```

In my template file I have this:

```
<script src="{% static "js/standalone.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    {# this is where it fetches the json and formats it correctly #}
    var js_variable = {{platformList | jsonify}};
    console.log(js_variable);
    function_in_standalone_js(js_variable);
</script>
```

The JSON outputs properly from that console.log(), but I get the error:

> ReferenceError: function_in_standalone_js is not defined

In my standalone Javascript:

```
var function_in_standalone_js = function(js_variable)
{
var options = js_variable['platforms'];
console.log(options)
}
```

Here's what the output would be, and what the console.log() gives (There are more than 3, but I didn't want to paste the entire thing):

> {"platforms": [{"slug": "saturn", "id": 32, "name": "Sega Saturn"}, {"slug": "mac", "id": 14, "name": "Mac"}, {"slug": "vc", "id": 47, "name": "Virtual Console (Nintendo)"}]}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried just running `function_in_standalone_js(js_variable);` in the browser console?

Comment: @IanAuld Yes, I get the same "not defined" error.

Comment: Is `js/standalone.js` showing a 404 in the network tab of your broswer dev tools?

Comment: @IanAuld No, in the network tab it says: "304: Not modified". Even if I go into "View page source" I can access the file and see it's contents.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your in line script in `$(document).ready(function(){<inline stuff here>})`?

Comment: @IanAuld Just attempted to do that. No success, same error.

Comment: Just used attempted again, the `$(document).ready`. Actually fixed it! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to different loading times of the JS in your template you should wrap your inline JS in `$(document).ready(function(){...})` to make sure it's run only after the rest of the document has loaded, including external JS files.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var js_variable = {{platformList | jsonify}};
      console.log(js_variable);
      function_in_standalone_js(js_variable);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

may be your standalone.js is getting loaded after the code in template hence the error

Comment: How would I correct this? In my template file I list the standalone.js as a script file before I list the code. 
**EDIT:** Even after putting the standalone js in my <head>, I still get the error.

Comment: do one thing define a simple js function without parameter define it in your js file and try to call it before console.log(), so you could know whether it loads or no

Comment: I still get the error: 
`ReferenceError: showTest is not defined`

In the standalone JS file: `function showTest() 
{
 console.log("Test!")
}
`

Comment: @AllenFernandes
Apparently my answer above doesn't answer your question...
Even though that error means that it doesn't load, apparently I have to specifically state. That no, it still cannot load the function showTest() before console.log()